# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS won't boot to desktop

Tags: 22.04, desktop-environments, gdm

I am running a VM of 22.04.1 LTS on my server running TrueNAS to host game servers and my discord bot. it has been fine since I installed it but due to its nature I leave it running without looking at it for extended periods of time. I tried to reboot it the other day as it was not logged in after a power cut and now it doesn't boot to desktop, just a flashing cursor where I can open terminal.

I am aware of this problem being answered elsewhere but I have tried every solution I have found without any success. I would not like to do a fresh install of ubuntu as it was a pain in the ass to get all the things working in the first place.

Thanks in advance.